# How do I stop execution inside exec command in Python 3?

Tags: python, exec

I have a following code:

```
code = """
print("foo")

if True: 
    return

print("bar")
"""

exec(code)
print('This should still be executed')
```

If I run it I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "untitled.py", line 10, in <module>
    exec(code)
  File "<string>", line 5
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
```

How to force `exec` stop without errors? Probably I should replace `return` with something? Also I want the interpreter work after `exec` call.

Comment: why are you using `exec` in the first place?

Comment: Why don't you want to use exceptions?

Comment: I don't want to use exceptions because I want to have an opportunity to keep the generated code readable.

Comment: @Fomalhaut well, unfortunately, this is what one would naturally use. What isn't readable about `raise SomeException`. Just wrap the whole thing in a function to keep things readable. Exceptions are idiomatic in Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, just do something like this:

```
class ExecInterrupt(Exception):
    pass

def Exec(source, globals=None, locals=None):
    try:
        exec(source, globals, locals)
    except ExecInterrupt:
        pass

Exec("""
print("foo")

if True: 
    raise ExecInterrupt

print("bar")
""")
print('This should still be executed')
```

If your worry is readability, functions are your first line of defense.

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in mechanism that allows you to abort execution of an `exec` call. The closest thing we have is [`sys.exit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit), but that exits the whole program, not just the `exec`. Fortunately, this can be worked around with a minor amount of exception handling boilerplate:

```
my_code = """
import sys

print("foo")

if True: 
    sys.exit()

print("bar")
"""

try:
    exec(my_code)
except SystemExit:
    pass
print('This is still executed')

# output:
# foo
# This is still executed
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, here's another way:

```
def breakable_exec(code):
    exec('for _ in [0]:' + '\n'.join("    " + line for line in code.splitlines()))

code = """
print("foo")

if True: 
    break

print("bar")
"""

breakable_exec(code)
# => foo
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work, return only works from within a defined function:

```
code = """
print("foo")

if not True:
    print("bar")
"""
exec(code)
print('This should still be executed')
```

but if you want to use return, you must do something like:

```
code = """
def func():
    print("foo")

    if True: 
        return

    print("bar")

func()    
"""
exec(code)
print('This should still be executed')
```