# exec() python command stops the whole execution

Tags: python, operating-system, exec, system

I am trying to run a script that sequentially changes some parameters in a config file (MET_config_EEv40.cfg) and runs a script ('IS_MET_EEv40_RAW.py') that retrieves these new config parameters:

```
config_filename = os.getcwd() + '/MET_config_EEv40.cfg'

import sys
parser = configparser.ConfigParser()
parser.read('MET_config_EEv40.cfg')
parser.set('RAW', 'product', 'ERA')
parser.set('RAW', 'gee_product', 'ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/HOURLY')
parser.set('RAW', 'indicator', 'PRCP')
parser.set('RAW', 'resolution', '11110')


with open('MET_config_EEv40.cfg', 'w') as configfile:
    parser.write(configfile)

## execute file
import sys

os.system(exec(open('IS_MET_EEv40_RAW.py').read()))
#exec(open('IS_MET_EEv40_RAW.py').read())

print('I am here')
```

After this execution, I get the output of my script as expected:

```
Period of Reference: 2005 - 2019
Area of Interest: /InfoSequia/GIS/ink/shp_basin_wgs84.shp
Raw data is up to date. No new dates available in raw data
Press any key to continue . . .
```

But it never prints the end line: I am here, so that means that after the execution of the script, the algorithm is terminated. That is not what I want it to do, as I would like to be able to change some other config parameters and run the script again.

That output is showed because of this line of the code:

```
if (delta.days<=1):
    sys.exit('Raw data is up to date. No new dates available in raw data')
```

So could be that sys.exit is ending both processes? Any ideas to replace sys.exit() inside the code to avoid this?

```
Im executing this file from a .bat file that contains the following:

@echo OFF

docker exec container python MET/PRCPmain.py

pause
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I stop execution inside exec command in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51905191/how-do-i-stop-execution-inside-exec-command-in-python-3)

Comment: Is there an `input` in your `IS_MET_EEv40_RAW.py` file?

Comment: @Chillie I think there is not.                                        
Importing config file ####################################################
config_general = configparser.RawConfigParser()
config_filename = os.getcwd() + '/MET_config_EEV40.cfg'
config_general.read(config_filename)

#########################  Retrieve attributes ##############################################
# General attributes
lot = config_general.get('GENERAL','lot')
version = config_general.get('GENERAL','version')
project_name = config_general.get('GENERAL','project_name')

Comment: Where does the `Press any key to continue . . .` come from?

Comment: it just takes parameters with get attribute and use them to perform functions

Comment: @Chillie it comes from the pause command in the bat file that I just included in the edited question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`exec(source, globals=None, locals=None, /)` does

> Execute the given source in the context of globals and locals.

So

```
import sys
exec("sys.exit(0)")
print("after")
```

is same as writing

```
import sys
sys.exit(0)
print("after")
```

which obviously terminate and does not print `after`.
`exec` has optional argument `globals` which you can use to provide your alternative to `sys` for example

```
class MySys:
    def exit(self, *args):
        pass
exec("sys.exit(0)",{"sys":MySys()})
print("after")
```

which does output

```
after
```

as it does use `exit` from MySys instance. If your codes make use of other things from `sys` and want it to work normally you would need method mimicking `sys` function in `MySys` class

Comment: This is very useful! Thanks!!